Can 3-way diverter valve be mounted other way round?
I bought a home with the following installation:

From the right side warm water goes in up and cold water goes out down. On the left side there is connection to the underfloor heating.
All great, but if you look at the 3-way valve in the middle, it is mounted other way round. Warm water goes in from the right side to the left, pump works that way. But the arrows on the valve are the other way.
Should I prioritize to remount the valve the other way, or is it supposed to work the same way from both ways? Thanks.

If the purpose of that three way valve is to reduce the temperature of the hot water by mixing in some cold water, then it is mounted the correct way around.
The arrows on the body of the three way valve are more an indication between which connections it can switch the water flows than that the arrow states a mandatory flow direction.

I do not know the purpouse, but "oooooh".  So when you have floorheating, you do not want the water temperature to hit too high temperature?

@KamilCuk, especially if your house has a mixture of radiated heat and underfloor heating, the appliance can easily be delivering water at 60 C. You do not want to have that kind of temperature through the floor that you walk on with your bare feet. Hence a mixing valve to mix in some cold water.
